# Update number of pages with selected objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I need some help with a problem I'm facing with pagination on AngularJS

Right now I have 3 tables, two of them have available items to select, and the third one, stores and show selected elements of the other tables, then I added pagination to each table, but I'm having some troubles with the selection table, If I add or remove elements individually, everything works as expected and the number of pages on selection table are updated.

The problem is when I use "Check All" function of the first table, the number of the pages doesn't get updated, I don't know what can I do in this case, I guess is something in check all funcition maybe but I run out of ideas right now

This is what I have so far:
http://embed.plnkr.co/e5P6iZ4W3P0Yb0YQy7Fu/preview

This is how the number of pages are calculated in numberOfSelectionPages function:

```
    $scope.numberOfSelectionPages = function() {
            return Math.ceil($scope.selection.length / $scope.pageSelSize);
 };
```

And this is how the template is created on the html file:

```
                    <div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="selection.length">
                    <ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
                        <li>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curSelPage == 0"
                             ng-click="curSelPage=curSelPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Page {{curSelPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfSelectionPages() }}</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            ng-disabled="curSelPage >= selection.length/pageSelSize - 1"
                            ng-click="curSelPage = curSelPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This is what I used for pagination:
http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/03/client-side-pagination-using-angular-js.html

I hope maybe somebody can give me a hand on this

Thanks in advice!